# Android strange behavior on orientation change with Custom View in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-custom-view, android-fragmentactivity, android-orientation

I have a `FragmentActivity` which shows a `Fragment` by defualt. The fragment consists of an `EditText`, a `TextView` and a Custom DropDown, made by extending `AutoCompleteTextView`.
If my custom `AutoCompleteTextView` is focused or the drop down list is open and I change the orientation of the device. I get following exception:

> Failed Looking up window
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window null does not exist

It works if the custom `AutoCompleteTextView` is not in focused state.
I've tried removing the focus in `onSaveInstanceState()` by making other layout get focus by `requestFocus()`
I've searched for this on the internet for more then 2 days, and it seems that no one has faced such issue before regarding **Custom Views** in context of fragments and orientation change.

Here is my FragmentActivity:

```
public class Balance_Inquiry extends FragmentActivity implements OnTouchListener, EventCallbackListener, DataCallBack,CustomResultReceiver.Receiver  {

LinearLayout balInquiryLayout;
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
FragmentManager fm;
Fragment fr;

//SQLiteDatabase sql;
//ConDb db;

public final static int ACTIVITY_ID = 2;
private Bundle orientationData;



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    try{
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int screenWidth = (int) (metrics.widthPixels * 0.90);

    setContentView(R.layout.common_blank_dialog);
    //Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler(this));
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler(App.context()));

    getWindow().setLayout(screenWidth, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    balInquiryLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dialogtoplayout);
    orientationData = savedInstanceState;
    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        fr = new Balance_Main_Fragment();
         fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
         fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
         fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.zoom_enter, R.anim.zoom_exit);
         fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.dialogtoplayout, fr,"tag1");
         fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
    else{
         fr = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag1");
    }


    balInquiryLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    balInquiryLayout.requestFocus();
    DisableKeyboard.hideKB(v, getApplicationContext());
    return false;
}




private AccountBean ab_;
private ValuesBean resp_;




public void show_result(){
    try{
      fr = new Balance_Result_Fragment();
         fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
         fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
         fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.zoom_enter, R.anim.zoom_exit);
         fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.dialogtoplayout, fr, "tag2");
         fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void hideResult(){


      fr = new Balance_Result_Fragment();
         fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.zoom_exit,R.anim.zoom_enter);
    fragmentTransaction.remove(fr).commit();


    //new Balance_Main_Fragment().clearAll();

}



@Override
public void onButtonClicked(int a) {


    switch(a){

            case 0:
                {


                    hideResult();

                    try{


                          fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                          Balance_Main_Fragment fre=(Balance_Main_Fragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag1");
                             fre.clearAll();

                         fre.enableButtons();
                         }
                         catch(Exception e){
                             e.printStackTrace();
                         }

                    break;
                }

            case 1:
            {
                show_result();
                break;
            }


    }

}







@Override
public void passData(String... a) {


}







@Override
public void passData(Object... a) {
    try{
     this.ab_=(AccountBean) a[0];
     this.resp_ = (ValuesBean) a[1];     
     }
    catch(ClassCastException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}







@Override
public Object[] getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new Object[]{this.ab_,this.resp_};
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if(MainExpandActivity.backApprove== true){
        if(ParserMain.isMyServiceRunning(MessengerService.class, this)){
        NetworkThread.stopServiceNow(Balance_Inquiry.this);
        NetworkThread.unBindServicePlz(Balance_Inquiry.this);
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    else{
        // do nothing here hehehehe
    }

}

@Override
public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, final Bundle resultData) {
    Log.e("activity", "activties onRecieveresul is called");
}

public void onDestroy(){
    //NetworkThread.unBindServicePlz(Balance_Inquiry.this);
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e("onDestory()", "onDestory() is called");
    if(isFinishing()){
        NetworkThread.unBindServicePlz(this.getApplicationContext());
        NetworkThread.stopServiceNow(this.getApplicationContext());
        Log.e("onDestory()", "isFinishing() block");
    }

}

public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

  if(hasFocus) 
     Toast.makeText(Balance_Inquiry.this, "focus gained", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  else
      Toast.makeText(Balance_Inquiry.this, "focus lost", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}



public void onPause(){
    Log.e("onPause()", "pause called");
    balInquiryLayout.requestFocus();

    super.onPause();

    }

}
```

Following is my Fragment class, posting only relevant snippets from it:

```
InstantAutoComplete accounts;  // custom View
LinearLayout balInq2ndLayout;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setRetainInstance(true);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    main_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_balance1, container,false);
    sub = (Button) main_view.findViewById(R.id.sub_bal);

    cancel = (Button) main_view.findViewById(R.id.cancel_bal);

    accounts = (InstantAutoComplete) main_view.findViewById(R.id.bal_accounts);

    mHat = new Handler();
    balInq2ndLayout = (LinearLayout) main_view.findViewById(R.id.balInq2ndLayout);
    balInq2ndLayout_2 = (LinearLayout) main_view.findViewById(R.id.balInq2ndLayout_2);


    macBalance = (TextView) main_view.findViewById(R.id.macbal_balinq);

    macBalance.setText(SessionInfo.getBalanceString()+SessionInfo.getMacBalance());
    bal_prog = (TextView) main_view.findViewById(R.id.bal_status);

    pb = (ProgressBar) main_view.findViewById(R.id.progressBarBalance);
    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    balInq2ndLayout.requestFocus();
    balInq2ndLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);
    balInq2ndLayout_2.setOnTouchListener(this);

    pin_no = (EditText) main_view.findViewById(R.id.bal_pin);

    bal_accountLocked = (EditText) main_view.findViewById(R.id.bal_accountlocked);

    bal_accountLocked.setEnabled(false);
    bal_accountLocked.setFocusable(false);
    bal_accountLocked.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    myData = new Bundle();

    if(savedInstanceState==null){

    bal_accountLocked.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    }
    else{

        pin_no.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("pin"));

        if(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("key")){
            bal_accountLocked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bal_accountLocked.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("locked"));
        }


        if(accounts.getText().toString().length()!=0){
            ab = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("ab");
        }

        if(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("progress")){

            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            disableButtons();
        }

        accounts.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("account"));

    }




    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler(App.context()));

    final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, ObjectsHolder.ab);
    accounts.setAdapter(adapter);

    accounts.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus){
                if(accounts.getText().length()==0){
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "focus lost", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                accounts.setText(saved1);
                DisableKeyboard.disableSoftInputFromAppearing(accounts, getActivity());

                    }
                }
            else if(hasFocus){
                DisableKeyboard.disableSoftInputFromAppearing(accounts, getActivity());
            }

        }
    });

    accounts.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            DisableKeyboard.disableSoftInputFromAppearing(accounts, getActivity());
            saved1=DisableKeyboard.showAll(accounts);
            if(accounts.getText().toString().length()==0){
                bal_accountLocked.setText("");
                bal_accountLocked.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });



    accounts.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id){
                Log.e("inside setOnItemSelectedListener", "this is called normally");
                //Toast.makeText(arg0.getContext(), "On item click: "+arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2), 1).show();
                ab= (AccountBean) adapter.getItem(position);

                //ab = (AccountBean) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                if(ab==null){
                    Log.e("ab object", "is null :(");
                }
                else{
                    bal_accountLocked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bal_accountLocked.setText(ab.getAccountNumber());
                }
                //saved1 = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
    }

    });

    return main_view;

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    balInq2ndLayout.requestFocus();
    DisableKeyboard.hideKB(v, getActivity());
    return false;
}


    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state){
      super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
      Log.e("onSaved", "onSaved is  called");
      balInq2ndLayout.requestFocus(); // setting request here to LinearLayout
      if(bal_accountLocked.isShown()){
      state.putString("locked", bal_accountLocked.getText().toString());
      state.putBoolean("key", true);
      }
      if(ab!=null){
        state.putParcelable("ab", ab);
      }
      state.putString("pin", pin_no.getText().toString());

      if(pb.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        state.putBoolean("progress", true);
        state.putBoolean("back", true);
      }

      if(accounts.getText().toString().length()!=0){
        state.putString("account", accounts.getText().toString());
      }

  }
```

Finally This is my custom AutoCompleteTextView

```
import android.content.Context;  
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;


public class InstantAutoComplete extends AutoCompleteTextView {
String savedTexti2;

public InstantAutoComplete(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public InstantAutoComplete(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1) {
    super(arg0, arg1);
}

public InstantAutoComplete(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1, int arg2) {
    super(arg0, arg1, arg2);
}

@Override
public boolean enoughToFilter() {
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction,
        Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
    super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
    if (focused) {
        performFiltering(getText(), 0);
        showAll();
    }
    else{
        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "works", 10).show();
        //restore();
    }

}


public void restore() {
    this.setText(savedTexti2);
}

public void showAll() {
    savedTexti2 = this.getText().toString();
    this.setText("");
    this.showDropDown();
    }





}
```

Here is the complete StackTrace:

> Failed looking up window
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window null does not exist
>   at com.android.server.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:9293)
>   at com.android.server.WindowManagerService.addWindow(WindowManagerService.java:1891)
>   at com.android.server.WindowManagerService$Session.add(WindowManagerService.java:6771)
>   at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact(IWindowSession.java:66)
>   at com.android.server.WindowManagerService$Session.onTransact(WindowManagerService.java:6743)
>   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:288)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
>   Attempted to add window with token that is not a window: null.  Aborting.

I've tried many different things, like removing focus from the AutoCompleteTextView , switching focus.. but nothing seems to work. If anyone can help me I would be grateful as I've visited each and every corner of stackoverflow but no luck. If someone has faced this issue and managed to solve it, please help a brother here.

**--EDIT--**

This issue was produced in emulator of API 8

Tested it on Emulator of JellyBean API 17 and it works fine. No exception. I wonder if its only related to lower APIs. Have to check them all one by one. sigh

Comment: This will not directly help you, but it seems that fragments are extremely unreliable [Advocating against fragments](https://corner.squareup.com/2014/10/advocating-against-android-fragments.html)

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Yes I've realized this the hard way.. Fragments are a pain in the a**

Comment: @downvoter care to comment the reason of downvote ?