# Garbage collection not triggered in app when largeHeap is enabled resulting in OOM

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

I have small Android test application where enabling `largeHeap` eventually causes Out of Memory Error because garbage collection never gets triggered.

This is the code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.oomtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int width = dm.widthPixels;
        int height = dm.heightPixels;

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background_image);
        iv.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.g01, width, height));
//        System.gc();
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(int width, int height, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
    {
        int inSampleSize = 1;
        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth)
        {
            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth)
            {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }
        return inSampleSize;
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
    {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options.outWidth, options.outHeight, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.oomtest" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

`drawable.g01` is JPEG image `2560x1707` pixels

When device is rotated image is reloaded. With `largeHeap` enabled `GC` never gets triggered and sequence of orientation changes will eventually result in `OOM`. That does not happen with disabled `largeHeap`. Also calling `System.gc()` after rotation resolves the issue.

Memory consumption with `largeHeap` enabled
[image: Memory consumption with largeHeap enabled]

Memory consumption with `largeHeap` enabled and `System.gc()` call
[image: Memory consumption with largeHeap enabled and System.gc() call]

Memory consumption with `largeHeap` disabled
[image: Memory consumption with largeHeap disabled]

I am able to reproduce this issue on `Samsung SM-T210 API 19` device. Same type of device with `API 16` works fine, as well as some other devices with `API 19` like `Samsung GT-N7100` and `Asus K01A`. Obviously it is some kind of bug that happens only on specific API/device combinations.

Questions are:

1. Is there anything inherently wrong with my code
2. Is there some other (better) way for resolving the issue other than calling `System.gc()`

Comment: Have you tried using [`WeakReference`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) for your Bitmaps ?

Comment: Can you try storing the reference to the bitmap in a member variable and then `recycle()` it in the `onDestroy()` method? Additionally, in your `onDestroy()`, set the image to null on your imageview and see if that helps with your problem.

Comment: @Sharpedge `WeakReference` makes no difference whatsoever because `ImageView` keeps holding the strong one. Even without any explicit bitmap reference - calling `iv.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(..));` makes no difference in behavior.

Comment: @kha the only thing achieved with `onDestroy()` and `recycle()` is slightly slower rise in memory consumption.

Comment: Is that all you have in your activity code? I see that you have added onConfigurationChanged, but the same is not added in Manifest file. It shouldn't be the reason for OOM though. Try to use a different thread for decoding bitmap and give a callback to the activity when that's done. And when you get the callback, set the bitmap to the image view. Make sure that the callback is passes as a weak reference.

Comment: @user3431672 good catch with redundant `onConfigurationChanged`, but it is not really relevant for the issue. That is just side-effect of copying code from real app while creating MCVE. I have edited the question with simplified code included.

Comment: You should try to decode the image in a different thread which doesn't have a strong reference to the activity or imageview. Once that's done you can give a callback to the activity. In this way you will have more control and you would also get a chance to cancel the thread, if the activity is destroyed.

Comment: @user3431672 problem is not in strong references but in fact that GC is never triggered.

Comment: GC will not be triggered when the reference is Strong.

Comment: Using Picasso library seems to eventually trigger GC, and keeps memory usage to about 80MB (almost double than my code on properly working devices when more images are used). Loading images with AsyncTask also triggers GC, but only when memory rises to whooping 300MB. Using LruCache makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to address this issue in case of Orientation Change only, Complete OOM Exception workaround is beyond the scope of this answer:

You can perform recycling of images in `ImageView` in `onDestroy()` because when the Orientation changes, activity's `onDestroy()` is called.

You have to differentiate whether the `onDestroy()` is called because of orientation change or not to do this, you should use is call `isFinishing()`

Following is a snippet to demonstrate this:

```
ImageView iv; // globally defined in class



 @Override
 protected void onDestroy(){
  super.onDestroy();
  if (isFinishing()) {
     // don't do anything activity is destroying because of other reasons
   }
  else{ // activity is being destroyed because of orientation change
    Drawable drawable = iv.getDrawable();
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
        Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        bitmap.recycle();
        iv.setImageBitmap(null);  // edited
    }
  }
}
```

Using `WeakReference` will help in addition to this, when creating the `Bitmap` object

```
WeakReference<Bitmap> bm; //initialize it however you want
```

** **EDIT** **

I know this won't make much difference, but for me it does. The only option android has left for us to save memory, is to reduce Image quality along with other methods like using [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html).

You could add another line before `options.inSampleSize` to reduce image's quality to save some memory.

```
options.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
```

Comment: Sorry, but this code does not solve the issue. Code is called, but it has no influence on memory growth.

Comment: After applying Does the application still crash because of OOM ?

Comment: Saving memory is not solution to the issue at hand. Saving memory just postpones the problem, but the problem is still there. I already have working solution and that is manual triggering of garbage collection with `System.gc()`. Triggering GC through debugger in AS also works. I was wondering if there is something else that might work. But, apparently issue really is in buggy GC on some devices.

Comment: I think `recycle()` should be invoked by the Bitmap instance created by `decodeSampledBitmapFromResource`; instead of passing directly the result to `iv.setImageBitmap` assign the value to a class variable first and invoke `recycle();` from that instance inside the destroy method as stated by @Sharpedge EDIT: set it as null as well after `recycle()`

Comment: @Paizo I have tried every possible combination of code involving `recycle()` and it makes no difference.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar you can conclude that android is totally random.. not all API levels behave the same, i posted a question with a strange problem which only occurred on lower APIs, with no work around and no bug report.Take a look at this [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30372385/android-strange-behavior-on-orientation-change-with-custom-view-in-fragment)